# Monit behin nginx proxy

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

I followed the monit documentation to put it behind a nginx proxy:

```
location /monit/ {
    rewrite ^/monit/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    proxy_pass   http://localhost:2812;
    proxy_redirect  http://localhost:2812 /monit;
    proxy_cookie_path / /monit/;
}
```

But keep getting the error:

```
17 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.26.16.6, server: myurl, request: "GET /monit/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://0.><tp://0.0.0.0:2812/", host: "inf-education-67.umwelt-campus.de"
```

My proxy for nodejs works just fine on the same nginx setuo.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was some other error in the monit configuration preventing monit from starting. So the above proxy settings are correct and work as they should.